# Java JTable: any default cell alignment technique?

Tags: jtable, text-alignment

I have a JTable with 9 columns, and I know I can create custom cell renderers for each column, at the expense of about 8 lines of code per renderer.

But all I really need is to display text placed in all cells as right-justified.  Is there any way to set this alignment for the whole table?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

John Doner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myTable.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < myTable.getModel().getColumnCount(); j++) {
      DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
         (DefaultTableCellRenderer)myTable.getCellRenderer(i, j);
      renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   } // End for(j)
} // End for(i)
```

Since each cell already has a renderer, this grabs each cell's existing `TableCellRenderer` from the `TableModel` and uses the built-in method `setHorizontalAlignment(int)` inherited from `JLabel`.

Hope that's what you're looking for!

Comment: Ok, I must be getting tired because I had to perform two edits to get this right (mostly minor issues), so hopefully I didn't screw something else up :)

Comment: I tried this, and it works perfectly well.  But here's mystery:  if I remove the do loops, and just set any single cell renderer's horizontal alignment to RIGHT, every cell in the table aligns the same.  Why is that?

Comment: Depending on how the `JTable` is created, a single `DefaultTableCellRenderer` may be used for all cells.  So if you're not defining your own renderers, you can get away with that.