# String should be in middle in JTable cell, Not by left

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is my table:

[image]

I like that `61` and `29` and `2013/09/20` be in the middle of cell, Not in the left side!

How can do it?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15016292/773623), the SSCCE as a solution.

Comment: There's this [question that looks very similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631985/java-jtable-any-default-cell-alignment-technique)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, which sets the horizontal alignment for each column by overriding the renderer.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(render);
}
```

Comment: Decided to change my comment as you asnwered my previous asking why not change the alignment of the current ones. One problem your solution might brings is if the actual renderers provide custom colors or other rendering tricks, those will be lost.

Comment: Agreed, for example, the last column is a Date which is probably using a DateRenderer.